# ui-view does not render with ng-boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngboilerplate

I am using ng-boilerplate and ui-router in my angular.js app. I have a 3 section layout, a topbar, a sidebar and a main layout. I use ng-switch to show different views in the main layout. Here is how my index.html looks like

```
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="HeaderTemplate"></div>
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="SidebarTemplate"></div>
<div ng-switch on="section">
     <div ui-view="secion1" class="secion1" ng-switch-when="secion1"></div>
     <div ui-view="secion2" class="secion2" ng-switch-when="secion2"></div>
     <div ui-view="secion3" class="secion3" ng-switch-when="secion3"></div>
</div>
```

My `HeaderTemplate` and `SidebarTemplate` are being rendered but the main layout is not being rendered.

I checked the value of `section` in `$scope`. It is `section1` which is fine and when i inspect in developer tools this is what the `DOM` looks like

```
<div ng-switch="" on="section">
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: section1 --><div ui-view="section1" class="section1 ng-scope" ng-switch-when="section1"><!-- ui-view-anchor --></div>
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: section2 -->
                <!-- ngSwitchWhen: section3 -->
            </div>
```

So here the correct section is chosen but the `ui-view` just shows a commented `ui-view-anchor`.(I have no idea what that is.). I looked at my html source to see if i am getting the templates for my `section1`, `section2`, etc and i see that i am getting them. I saw that in the `templates-app.js`, i am getting the html for my sections. Any idea why it is not rendering the html when it is getting it? My `$stateProvider` configuration looks like this

```
$stateProvider.state('section1', {
            url: '/section1',
            views: {
                "section1": {
                    controller: 'Section1Ctrl',
                    templateUrl: 'section1/section1.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data: { pageTitle: 'Section 1' }
        });
```

and so on.

Comment: Are you sure that current route is in fact '/section1' ?

Comment: yes. i see that in my location bar. Its `index.html#/section1`

Comment: Is it necessary to use ngSwitch here? Wouldn't it be better to use single uiView that fetches proper template for each route?

Comment: I wanted to avoid nested-states.

Comment: Well, I would suggest you to reconsider this choice. Right now you have to both specify section name in URL, ngSwitch and probably in controller that sets scope variable. So you have 2 or 3 places where you reuse this string. It's not really change-proof, you can always forget where you have to change something later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ui-router v0.2.8` is broken or not compatible with `angular.js v1.2.12`. I switched back to `ui-router v0.2.7` everything works fine